# How could I trigger onload events in Third Party JS files using React-Router-Dom when routes change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

We have cases where externally hosted third party javascript files need to have onload events triggered when the user changes routes in our react app. I have been successful in calling Globally Scoped Functions using useEffect and useLocation. I was also able to manually call Globally Scoped Named functions in a similar manner. However I have not been able to find a solution to trigger onload events like window.onload, domContentLoaded or readyStateChange. Is their a way to force those functions to run?

We also tried dangerouslySetInnerHtml and this works fine like the below when the page is loaded, but not when the user changes routes to a specific page.

Our nuclear option we may need to consider is forcing a page reload when a user uses internal navigation and avoiding react-router-dom Links completely. Any help to avoid that would be appreciated.

```
const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Load external script here based on location or other conditions
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src =
      'https://externalScript/index.js';
    // script.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      // Cleanup script here if needed
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [location]);
  return null;
}
```

Other Option for Globally Scoped Named Functions:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const existingScript = document.getElementById('someID');

    if (!existingScript) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://externalScript/index.js';
      script.id = 'someID';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.onload = () => {
        if (window.HelloWorld && typeof window.HelloWorld === 'function') {
          window.HelloWorld(); // Call the function defined in the loaded script
        }
        if (callback) {
          callback(); // Call the provided callback function
        }
      };
    } else if (callback) {
      callback(); // Call the provided callback function
    }
  }, [callback]);

  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.HelloWorld && typeof window.HelloWorld === 'function') {
      window.HelloWorld(); // Call the function defined in the loaded script
    }
  }, [location]);

  return null; // This component doesn't render anything
```